# CakePHP: Why entity validation is on Table class intead of Entity class?

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

If the CakePHP validations valids entities, why the rules is set on table class intead Entity class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's the table class that consumes the entities, hence its the tables responsibility to provide the contract that defines what's valid and what's not.